# Can I control what Outlook pastes when I copy a sender/recipient from a message?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts

When I select a sender or recipient in a message and copy/paste it in a plain text document I get the name of the person + the e-mail address wrapped in angle brackets.
E.g.:

```
Matthew Johnson <m.johnson@email.com>
```

Is it possible to direct Outlook to copy other information stored on the persons contact card as well?
E.g. a persons title:

```
Matthew Johnson <m.johnson@email.com> CEO
```

Comment: You may want to add what program (notepad, Word, etc.) you are pasting the information into. IMO, I don't think it is possible without some serious VBA coding, if it can even be done. You are asking how to have one program lookup and copy more information than you have selected, then paste it into another program. That is quite a task.

Comment: I paste it into a plain text environment (e.g. notepad). When I select it only the name is visible in Outlook, however when I paste it somehow the e-mail belonging to that name is looked up and pasted as well. I was hoping there was a setting that governed what fields were pasted when a sender/recipient is copied from a message.

Comment: It doesn't look up the email address. What you are copying is actually a hyperlink which contains the email address. That is why when you paste it as text you see it that way. There is not action going on when you copy other than copy. Hope that makes sense. Hence, the reason I said it would be quite a task to program something as you described. Have you researched anything on the topic?